# Remove the first bracket and its content in a string with R

Tags: r, string, split

For instance:

```
a = '[122][md]+'
b = '[3][md+5]x'
```

I want to remove the first bracket and the contents in this bracket, and get:

```
a = '[md]+'
b= '[md+5]x'
```

Comment: `sub('.*[1[]',"[",c(a,b))` which results in
`[1] "[md]+"   "[md+5]x"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex

```
> gsub('\\[[0-9]+\\]', '', a)
[1] "[md]+"
```

Comment: You don't want to use `gsub` here, but rather just `sub` (the `g` stands for greedy, meaning it will apply the sub as many times as possible).  [See this demo](http://rextester.com/WXMWV16149) to see what can happen with `gsub`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sub` with the pattern `\[.*?\]` and replace that with empty string.

```
a <- '[122][md]+'
b <- '[3][md+5]x'
sub("\\[.*?\\]", "", a)
sub("\\[.*?\\]", "", b
```

### Demo